# Extracting strings from grep result

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, grep

I am running this command to extract some data from our log file.
   I am getting full line but what I am interested in the value associated with Message ID.

command I am Running -

```
grep -B 2 UPDATE_CHAIR_DESK_REQ Application.log | head -1000
```

Output I am getting

```
< MessageId :ID:414d51204541495052475731202020205143d55bf3f13821>
 < AppServiceID :abcfcdd>
 < ReplyToQName :UPDATE_CHAIR_DESK_REQ>
--
< MessageId :ID:414d51204541495052475731202020205143d55bf7f13821>
 < AppServiceID :abcfcdd>
 < ReplyToQName :UPDATE_CHAIR_DESK_REQ>
--
< MessageId :ID:414d51204541495052475731202020205143d55bf7f13821>
 < AppServiceID :abcfcdd>
 < ReplyToQName :UPDATE_CHAIR_DESK_REQ>
--
< MessageId :ID:414d51204541495052475731202020205143d55bfbf13821>
 < AppServiceID :abcfcdd>
 < ReplyToQName :UPDATE_CHAIR_DESK_REQ>
--
< MessageId :ID:414d51204541495052475731202020205143d55bfbf13821>
 < AppServiceID :abcfcdd>
 < ReplyToQName :UPDATE_CHAIR_DESK_REQ>
--
< MessageId :ID:414d51204541495052475731202020205143d55bfff13821>
 < AppServiceID :abcfcdd>
 < ReplyToQName :UPDATE_CHAIR_DESK_REQ>**
```

What I am looking for is the values in front of MessageId :ID: , it is always of 48 characters in length. I want to enhance my grep command to get only these values in a column format either on screen or on file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With awk, you could use:

```
awk -F'[:>]' '
    $1 ~ /MessageId/ {msgId = $3}
    $2 == "UPDATE_CHAIR_DESK_REQ" {print msgId}
' Application.log
```

Comment: Thank You Glenn, it has worked exactly per my requirement.

Answer (score 1):

```
grep -B 2 UPDATE_CHAIR_DESK_REQ Application.log | egrep -o ':ID:.{48}'
```

Comment: To get *just* the id, you could use `grep -oP 'MessageId :ID:\K.{48}'`

Comment: or  add `| cut -d: -f3`